# Tailwind purge not rendering styles with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

In a new WordPress project I'm using Tailwind CSS with ACF flexible (block) content. 
Now I've created a "spacer" block, that can be used in between other blocks.

The thing is, Tailwind JIT is not purging the PHP file correctly.
I works good if I echo out the full sting like "h-20" or "sm:h-40", but when I'm creating the string with some PHP filters, it won't work.

For example:

```
<?php

$group = !empty(get_sub_field('spacer')) ? get_sub_field('spacer') : $args;

if (!empty($group['value'])) :
    
    $val = intval(str_replace('h-', '', $group['value'])); // input = h-28 , output = 28
    $val_half = 'h-' . round($val / 2);
    $val_third = 'sm:h-' . round($val / 3 * 2);
    $val_full = 'lg:h-' . $val;
    $spacing = $val_half . ' ' . $val_third . ' ' . $val_full; // output = h-14 sm:h-19 lg:h-28
    ?>

    <!-- Spacer -->
    <div class="spacer relative body-font w-full <?php echo $spacing; ?>"></div>  

<?php endif;
```

In the example above, the only available height class is h-14. I think because this doen't use a breakpoint? Not sure.

I'm using Laravel Mix for compiling my SASS and JS. 
Here's my config:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const local = require('./src/assets/js/utils/local-config');

const domain = 'fides.test';
const homedir = require('os').homedir();

require('laravel-mix-versionhash');
require('laravel-mix-tailwind');

mix.setPublicPath('./webroot/wp-content/themes/qore/dist');

mix.webpackConfig({
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery",
    }
});

if (local.proxy) {
    mix.browserSync({
        watch: true,
        proxy: 'https://' + domain,
        host: domain,
        open: 'external',
        injectChanges: true,
        https: {
            key: homedir + "/.config/valet/Certificates/" + domain + ".key",
            cert: homedir + "/.config/valet/Certificates/" + domain + ".crt"
        },
        files: [
            './webroot/wp-content/themes/qore/**/*.{json,php,twig,blade.php}',
            './src/assets/**/*.{html,js,vue}',
        ],
        callbacks: {
            ready: function (err, bs) {
                console.log('callbacks');
                mix.sass('./src/assets/scss/style.scss', 'css');
            }
        }
    });
}

mix.tailwind();
mix.copy('./src/assets/fonts', './webroot/wp-content/themes/qore/dist/fonts');
mix.copy('./src/assets/img/', './webroot/wp-content/themes/qore/dist/img');
mix.copy('./src/assets/videos', './webroot/wp-content/themes/qore/dist/videos');
mix.js('./src/assets/js/vendor.js', 'js');
mix.js('./src/assets/js/script.js', 'js');
mix.sass('./src/assets/scss/style.scss', 'css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    // mix.versionHash();
    mix.sourceMaps();
}
```

I am not sure what I should change to make this get to work. I've checked:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-mix-purgecss but that seems to be ignored completely.

Hope one of you guys know what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid purgeCSS does not run your code and cannot 'see' these classes. So it's not adding them to the CSS file.

As per the Tailwind documentation on 'Writing purgeable HTML' [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)

> That means that it is important to avoid dynamically creating class strings in your templates with string concatenation, otherwise PurgeCSS won’t know to preserve those classes.

Comment: Yea that was probably the case, I have replaced Laravel Mix with the Tailwind CLI and everything works fine now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Loosie94 no problem, please mark this as the accepted answer if it was of help. Thank you.